# Making an Oracle UNION query using the same data twice more efficient

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wondering how I can do this without having to write out (or make the DB process) the main part of this query twice.

My scenario is that I am querying an Oracle enterprise database (I am limited by the DBA, so some solutions MAY not work, but I'm not sure to what degree I'm limited until I try and don't know where to go with this yet).

Currently, my query looks as follows:

```
    SELECT
        a.Field1,
        a.Field2,
        b.Field3,
        b.Field4,
        c.Field5
    FROM
        a,
        b,
        c,
    WHERE
            a.FieldX = b.FieldX
        AND
            b.FieldY = c.FieldY

UNION
  (
    SELECT
        d.Field6 as Field1,
        d.Field7 + d.Field8 as Field2,
        MainQuery.Field3,
        MainQuery.Field4,
        MainQuery.Field5
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                a.Field1,
                a.Field2,
                b.Field3,
                b.Field4,
                c.Field5
            FROM
                a,
                b,
                c,
            WHERE
                    a.FieldX = b.FieldX
                AND
                    b.FieldY = c.FieldY
                AND
                    a.FieldZ = 'XXXX'
        ) MainQuery,

        d
    WHERE
        MainQuery.Field1 = d.Field6
  )
```

Simply put, I have a main query (the first part) that returns the bulk of my results and then I'm repeating the main query with an extra limitation (`a.FieldZ = 'XXXX'`) and pulling data from this query AND a second table and appending it onto the main query using a `UNION`.

The main challenge I'm facing is that the definitions of `Field1` & `Field2` change between the 2 queries, so I can't figure out how to just do a simple join. But I'm sure there has to be a way to accomplish this without having to make the DB query the same data twice.

Any thoughts about how to make this query more efficient??

Thanks!!

---

Based upon the comments, to explain a bit more about this query - What I am trying to do is get my entire unvierse of data in the first half of the query and then append on extra rows in the second half of the query for the records where `a.FieldZ = 'XXXX'` where the calculation is slightly different for `Field1` and `Field2`

Comment: Can you post the table definitions please, it would help.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in the real world with this query?

Comment: first, your pseudo query is wrong ( selecting field6 whereas you only select till 5 in the subquery ). Next, if I understand right, you want to have different values for FieldA depending on if FieldZ is XXX or not. There are better solutions to do that then (eg `DECODE` )

Comment: Your result will have more rows than the first half of the query.  So, rows with a.FieldZ = 'xxxx' will be duplicated.  I assume this is intentional.

Comment: @Najzero, my definition isn't wrong - The `Field6` comes from the `d` table that's joined on to the other query

Comment: I updated the question with a bit more information - Thanks to all of you for your help so far - Hopefully the solution is clean and easy!! @twoleggedhorse, I didn't post any table definitions since I made up this scenario to explain the situation, this is not the real query, but, rather, more of a conceptual question about how to do the `UNION` without having to repeat the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, following your comments, your requirement seems to be "column 2 is to be taken from table `M`. Additionaly, when `M.fieldZ = 'XXX'` an extra row with the field needs from table `D` needs to be added."

In that case you will have to either use a UNION ALL or duplicate your records by joining to a 2 row table. You can use the `WITH` clause to reuse a subquery in your SELECT. This will make it more readable and the optimizer may decide to run the query once only (by saving the result of the subquery in temp).

```
WITH mainquery AS (SELECT /* your main query */)
SELECT *
  FROM mainquery
 UNION ALL
SELECT field1, d.field2 /*, ... */
  FROM (SELECT * FROM mainquery WHERE fieldZ = 'XXX') m
  JOIN d ON m.field1 = d.field6
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think this is the same problem I mentioned to Paul - Since I want data BOTH ways when FieldZ = 'XXXX', this doesn't give me that since the Case statement will only give me the second half of the query's results. No?

Comment: You're right my query will not return two records if `fieldZ='XXX'`. I think you will have to use a UNION (you probably want to use UNION ALL by the way) or duplication of rows by joining to a 2 row table (which would probably result in the same plan). See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that I believe gives you the answer you need.  Without a significant amount of data I can't tell if it would be any faster or not.  Here you will be scanning the temp table a couple times but that may be less work if the base query returns a small set of data from tables a, b, c and d.

```
with foo as 
   (SELECT
        a.Field1,
        a.Field2,
        a.FieldZ,
        b.Field3,
        b.Field4,
        c.Field5
    FROM
        a,
        b,
        c
    WHERE
            a.FieldX = b.FieldX
        AND
            b.FieldY = c.FieldY
)
select Field1
       ,field2
       ,field3
       ,field4
       ,field5 
from foo
union
select
 d.Field6 as Field1
 ,d.Field7 ||'+'|| d.Field8 as Field2
 ,foo.Field3
 ,foo.Field4
 ,foo.Field5
from foo
join d on foo.field1 = d.field6
where foo.fieldz = 'XXXX'
```

Comment: Thanks @jwhite9 - That is the way I ended up going with this. simply accepted Vincent's answer since he posted it sooner. Thank you for this and your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

use a `case` statement (http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php)

e.g.

```
select case when FieldZ = 'XXXX' then Field6 else Field1 end as Field1,
       case when FieldZ = 'XXXX' then Field7 + Field8 else Field2 as Field2,
       Field3,
       Field4,
       Field5
from   a join b on a.FieldX = b.FieldX
       join c on b.FieldY = c.FieldY
       left join d on a.Field1 = d.Field6
```

Comment: thank you for the code, but this doesn't really solve the problem since I want data **BOTH** ways when `FieldZ = 'XXXX'` where as the `Case` statement will only give me the second half of the query's results. No??

Comment: True. Where does the data go? Application, report or elsewhere?

Comment: A report - Basically loaded into an Excel sheet

Comment: Perhaps you could select all of the data you want in one query (i.e. `select Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7 + Field8...` then sort it out in excel?

Comment: ... That's what I ended up doing :) - I was **HOPING** there was a way to do it in my SQL instead, but at least I now feel better that it wasn't a trivial solution that was just outside of my range of ability...

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is *not* to duplicate the XXXX records, then you can simplify the query to an appropriate join with case statements:

```
SELECT (case when a.FieldZ = 'XXXX' then a.Field1 else d.Field6 end) as Field1,
       (case when a.FieldZ = 'XXXX' then a.Field2 else d.Field7 + d.Field8 end) as Field2,
        b.Field3,
        b.Field4,
        c.Field5
FROM a join
     b
     on a.FieldX = b.FieldX join
     C
     on b.FieldY = c.FieldY left outer join
     d
     on A.Field1 = d.Field6 and
        a.FieldZ = 'XXXX'
```

If you are duplicating these records, then some sort of `union all` would seem necessary.